# Setting wmode with oembed

Tags: youtube-api

Can you set wmode using oembed? Vimeo seems to support it but youtube doesn't seem to have any docs available specifying what options are available.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, we don't support very much by way of parameters to the initial request that affect the type of response you get back.

You'd have to manually edit the response you get back from the YouTube oEmbed service to add in that parameter. (Which obviously partially defeats the purpose of using oEmbed.)